# CMS for .Net web applications

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system

i am working on a web application that now requires a CMS.

Could you suggest me a product that grant integration with my existing application.

The latter is implemented using .Net framework 3.5 Linq to sql and SQL Server 2008

I may consider even not open source product (affordable price)

i want to create a Master page and allow the application's users to modify the content.

Ideally give them the ability to add controls such as image sliders (but this is not the main scope)

Main objective is the ability to modify the content usually text. Bu more is always better........

Thanks

Comment: look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836/your-experience-with-net-based-cms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/  is a good open source choice.

Comment: I've used it with great success on several projects.  It's very flexible and easy to code against.

Answer (score 2):

http://n2cms.com/ is very powerful cms that can be integrated with your application.

Answer (score 1):

[Graffiti](http://graffiticms.com/) is now Open Source. I'm not sure how it integrates with an existing application.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint is the obvious answer, considering it's an ASP.NET application itself. It's free with Windows Server 2003 or 2008.

Answer (score 0):

[Umbraco](http://umbraco.org/) is fantastic and free. Allowing you to integrate many plugins. If you are a developer you will probably fall in live as it offers a lot of integration.

Answer (score 0):

[DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com) has a great (if not long winded) video intro and online demo so you can see how it works.